Got 403 error instead of 404 error in Spring Security
I expect a 404 error when requesting a non-existent URL, but I'm only receiving a 403 error.
I can't find how to solve this problem. This is my code.
I think Spring Security filter throws a 403 error first, which prevents Spring MVC from checking the existence of the URL.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .sessionManagement(
                manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                .requestMatchers("/", "/error", "/api/v1/auth/login")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated())
            .build();
    }
}

Thank you for your response.
Someone told me that adding '/error' to the permitted URLs would make it work, but it did not.

its because you have these 2 lines .anyRequest().authenticated())

duplicate question
